# Cutoff in Closeness/Betweenness Centrality in python igraph

Tags: python, igraph

I am currently working a large graph, with 1.5 Million Nodes and 11 Million Edges.
For the sake of speed, I checked the benchmarks of the most popular graph libraries: iGraph, Graph-tool, NetworkX and Networkit. And it seems iGraph, Graph-tool and Networkit have similar performance. And I eventually used iGraph.

With the directed graph built with iGraph, the pagerank of all vertices can be calculated in 5 secs. However, when it came to Betweenness and Closeness, it took forever for the calculation.

In the documentation, it says that by specifying "CutOff", iGraph will ignore all path with length < CutOff value.

I am wondering if there a rule of thumb to choose the best CutOff value to choose?

Comment: see my answer and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cutoff` really depends on the application and on the netwrok parameters (# nodes, # edges).

- It's hard to talk about closeness threshold, since it depends greatly on other parameters (# nodes, # edges,...).
- One thing you can know for sure is that every closeness centrality is somewhere between 2/[n(n-1)] (which is minimum, attained at path) and 1/(n-1) (which is maximum, attained at clique or star).
- Perhaps better question would be about Freeman centralization of closeness (which is somehow normalized version of closeness that you can better compare between various graphs).

---

**Suggestion**:

You can do a grid search for different cutoff values and then choose the one that makes more sense based on your application.